# Express-jwt is not returning any response

Tags: authentication, jwt, amazon-dynamodb, express-jwt

I'm trying to create a Login functionality using express-jwt, and using the middleware function in my `app.js` file. But whenever I'm trying to send a get request using the `postman`, it sending request for infinite of time and never returns back any error or success message.
I'm using `dynamoDB` as database.

here's my `Login.js` file

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-2" });

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  user_type = "customer";
  const email = req.body.email;
  docClient.get(
    {
      TableName: "users",
      Key: {
        user_type,
        email,
      },
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send("Invalid username or password");
      } else {
        if (data && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data.Item.password)) {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              email: data.Item.email,
            },
            process.env.SECRET,
            { expiresIn: "1d" }
          );
          res.status(200).send({ user: data.Item.email, token: token });
        } else {
          res.status(400).send("Password is wrong");
        }
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's my `jwt.js` file:

```js
const expressJwt = require("express-jwt");
require("dotenv").config();

function authJwt() {
  const secret = process.env.SECRET;
  return expressJwt({
    secret,
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
  });
}

module.exports = authJwt;
```

And I'm trying to use the `expressJwt` like this in my `app.js` file:

```js
app.use(authJwt); //If I'm not using this, then the code works fine without API protection
```

Can Anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?
Any help from your side is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Remove function from your jwt.js ,it should look like this

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
const secret = process.env.secret

const authJwt = expressJwt({
secret,
algorithms:['HS256']
 })
module.exports = authJwt;
```